# Why does CatBoost download additional things during installation?

Tags: installation, catboost

Installing CatBoost on a Mac, I get messages like this:

```
me$ ../../ya make -r
Downloading http://storage.mds.yandex.net/get-devtools-opensource/479623/a4d31a25903254935156e2c3a2c740fb [..] OK
Downloading http://storage.mds.yandex.net/get-devtools-opensource/373962/301992658 [..............] OK
Info: will fetch 'YMake' from sandbox

|49.0%| [LD] $(B)/tools/enum_parser/enum_parser/enum_parser{, .dSYM/Contents/Resources/DWARF/enum_pa|50.2%| [LD] $(B)/tools/enum_parser/enum_parser/enum_parser{, .dSYM/Contents/Resources/DWARF/enum_pa|84.1%| [LD] $(B)/contrib/tools/protoc/plugins/cpp_styleguide/cpp_styleguide{,...
```

Why? What is all that about? Is there some way I can easily verify that CatBoost is not one grand phishing scam?

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure that it's the Yandex build system.

Comment: Could you elaborate on this a little?  Why wouldn't the build system be part of the git repo that I cloned originally?

Comment: Maybe related -- I'm getting mixed messages about this being an "open source" project. Techcrunch said CatBoost is "based on a proprietary algorithm".  Could some of that downloaded material include binaries for which they are not sharing the source?  If so is this truly "open source"?

Answer (score 1):

You can work using catboost library along with other essential data science libraries using the [Dockerfile](https://github.com/datmo/docker-files/blob/master/cpu/catboost/Dockerfile). Else, you can also try using [datmo](https://datmo.com) in order setup environment and track machine learning projects for making it reproducible.